# VS Code Pymakr - The terminal process command failed to launch

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install Pymakr for VS Code, and I've used VS Code before but when I download this it doesn't stop giving me the error "The terminal process command "node.exe" failed to launch" (see picture below) and the whole program just freezes up and I can't do anything. I've tried reinstalling the extension, reinstalling VS Code, not using any other extensions, etc. But nothing seems to be working, any ideas?

The error it gives me:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I just needed to install the node.js from the internet